# Mathematical proof of Regge symmetry

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

In the representation theory of the group $SU_2$ a big role is played by so-called $6j-$symbols. Let me sketch its definition (some other interpretations could be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9812013.pdf)).

Denote a representation of highest weight $a$ by $V_a.$ The space of invariants
$$
Inv(V_a \otimes V_b \otimes V_c \otimes V_d)
$$
has two natural bases coming from pairings
$$
Inv(V_a \otimes V_b \otimes V_e) \otimes Inv(V_e^* \otimes V_c \otimes V_d ) \longrightarrow Inv(V_a \otimes V_b \otimes V_c \otimes V_d)
$$
and
$$
Inv(V_a \otimes V_c \otimes V_f) \otimes Inv(V_f^* \otimes V_b \otimes V_d ) \longrightarrow Inv(V_a \otimes V_b \otimes V_c \otimes V_d)
$$
for various $e$ and $f$. A $6j-$symbol
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the corresponding coefficient of an operator on the space
$$
Inv(V_a \otimes V_b \otimes V_c \otimes V_d),
$$
sending the first basis to the second.

These numbers poses a surprising number of symmetries. The most surprising one is the famous  *Regge symmetry*:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & s-b & s-c\\
d & s-e & s-f\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where
$$
s=\frac{b+c+e+f}{2}.
$$

**Question:** How to prove this statement? In physics books it is usually derived as a corollary of a direct computation. Also, any mathematical interpretation of these symmetries will be of great interest to me.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603398

Comment: It's worth remarking that since this question was first asked, the [OP has come up with his own proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.01141).